# How can I fix my function on finding the determinant of an N by N matrix?

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

Here is my code:

```
def det(mat):
    if len(mat) < 2 or len(mat[0]) < 2:
        return None
    else:
        if len(mat) == 2 and len(mat[0]) == 2:
            return ((mat[0][0] * mat[1][1])-(mat[0][1] * mat[1][0]))
        elif len(mat) > 2 and len(mat[0]) > 2:
            tot = 0
            n = len(mat)
            for i in range(n):
                num = mat[0][i]
                smaller = []
                x = 0
                for j in range(1,n):
                    row = mat[j]
                    row.pop(i)
                    smaller.append(row)
                tot += ((-1)**i)*(num * det(smaller))
            return tot
```

When i use this line to test my code:

```
print(det([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]))
```

This is the error i get:

```
    tot += ((-1)**i)*(num * det(smaller))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I have tried changing the code within the each selection, and I have tried to change the conditions of these selections. Please may someone help me find the cause of the error so I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There are paths through your function that do not return anything explicitly, and therefore return `None`.  I assume that what is happening is that a recursive call to the function is returning None, and then you are trying to multiply that returned value by `num` in the second to last line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The first iteration of the function recursively calls itself.  Then the second iteration calls itself again.  When it does so, it passes a value of `[[1], [1]]`, and so it gets back `None` (because a 1x2 matrix has no determinant).  It then tries to multiply that returned value by `num`, which leads to the error you are getting.

To fix this, you need to make sure that when your function recursively calls itself, it either always gets back a valid numeric value, or it tests the value that is returned and does something appropriate if it gets back a `None` value.

Since there is no valid value to return for the determinant of a 1x2 matrix, your logic is somehow flawed for asking itself to compute such a value.